# How to start stopwatch from state time using Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, stopwatch

I have a stopwatch code using Vue 3 and Vuex that has functions that can start, stop and reset.

This is the code :

**store/stopwatch/index.js**

```
export default {
  state: {
    time: "00:10.000",
    timeStarted: null,
    timeBegan: null,
    timeStopped: null,
    stoppedDuration: 0,
    started: null,
    running: false,
    temp: {
      min: "0",
      sec: "0",
      ms: "0",
      secondsPassed: 0
    }
  },
  actions: {
    start({ state, commit, dispatch }) {
      if (state.running) return;
      if (state.timeBegan === null) {
        state.timeBegan = new Date();
      }

      if (state.timeStopped !== null) {
        state.stoppedDuration += new Date() - state.timeStopped;
      }

      commit("start", {
        callback: () => {
          dispatch("clockRunning");
        }
      });
    },
    async clockRunning({ state, commit, dispatch }) {
      let currentTime = new Date();
      let timeElapsed = new Date(
        currentTime - state.timeBegan - state.stoppedDuration
      );
      let min = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes();
      let sec = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds();
      let ms = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds();

      commit("newTemp", {
        key: "secondsPassed",
        value: parseInt(Math.abs((state.timeStarted - new Date()) / 1000), 10)
      });

      if (state.running) {
        await dispatch("zeroPrefix", { num: min, digit: 2 }).then(
          (zeroPrefixResponse) => {
            commit("newTemp", {
              key: "min",
              value: zeroPrefixResponse
            });
          }
        );

        await dispatch("zeroPrefix", { num: sec, digit: 2 }).then(
          (zeroPrefixResponse) => {
            commit("newTemp", {
              key: "sec",
              value: zeroPrefixResponse
            });
          }
        );

        await dispatch("zeroPrefix", { num: ms, digit: 3 }).then(
          (zeroPrefixResponse) => {
            commit("newTemp", {
              key: "ms",
              value: zeroPrefixResponse
            });
          }
        );
        state.time =
          state.temp.min + ":" + state.temp.sec + "." + state.temp.ms;
      }
    },
    zeroPrefix(context, payload) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let zero = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < payload.digit; i++) {
          zero += "0";
        }
        resolve((zero + payload.num).slice(-payload.digit));
      });
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    newTemp(state, payload) {
      state.temp[payload.key] = payload.value;
    },
    addSecondPassed(state, second) {
      state.temp.secondsPassed += second;
    },
    resetSecondPassed(state) {
      state.temp.secondsPassed = 0;
    },
    start(state, payload) {
      state.started = setInterval(() => {
        payload.callback();
      }, 10);
      state.running = true;
    },
    stop(state) {
      state.running = false;
      state.timeStopped = new Date();
      clearInterval(state.started);
    },
    reset(state) {
      state.running = false;
      clearInterval(state.started);
      state.stoppedDuration = 0;
      state.timeBegan = null;
      state.timeStopped = null;
      state.time = "00:10.000";
    }
  },
  getters: {}
};
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span class="time">{{ $store.state.stopwatch.time }}</span>
    <br />
    <button @click="start">Start</button>
    <button @click="stop">Stop</button>
    <button @click="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    start() {
      this.$store.dispatch("start");
    },
    stop() {
      this.$store.commit("stop");
    },
    reset() {
      this.$store.commit("reset");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This is the demo code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-start-stopwatch-from-state-time-using-vue-js-71imt?file=/src/App.vue:0-464)

What happens with the code above by starting from the 10 seconds and then clicking the start button, seconds starting from the number 0 then 1,2,3. do not continue from number 10.

How to start stopwatch from state time with 10 seconds?

So when click the start button, seconds continue from 10 then to 11,12,13 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is that the 10s is not added to the timeBegan. If you subtract the 10 seconds, it should work.

```js
if (state.timeBegan === null) {
  state.timeBegan = new Date() - 10_000;
}
```

On a side note, a mutation should be limited to just the mutation

This code is adding and removing interval from within the mutation and goes against how mutations are supposed to work.

```js
    start(state, payload) {
      state.started = setInterval(() => {
        payload.callback();
      }, 10);
      state.running = true;
    },
    stop(state) {
      state.running = false;
      state.timeStopped = new Date();
      clearInterval(state.started);
    },
```

And executing a callback from the mutation is also not good. Not that it won't work, but it's creating a weird state flow that goes against the principles of how the store works.

Comment: Is there a way to use `state time: "00:10.000"` as a start time reference? do not use the number `10_000`. because my needs will change the `state time` from time to time and run the time according to the changed `state time`. So I just `set` the `state` at the `state time` to change the initial time and when the stopwatch is started, it will run according to the initial time that has been `set` in the `state`. I'm confused if I have to change manually with an example number like `10_000`. i have tried with `state.timeBegan = new Date() - state.time` but it doesn't work

Comment: you could also adjust the `state.stoppedDuration`‍♂️ but the value of `state.time` gets overwritten so that's not the variable to change.